# PowerShell PSCustomObject select property name by location

Tags: object, powershell, properties

Suppose I have a `PSCustomObject` named `$Stuff` like this:

```
$Stuff = ("Green", "Aubergine"),("Yellow", "Banana") | 
% {[PSCustomObject]@{'Colors'=$_[0];'Items'=$_[1]}}

$Stuff | Format-Table
Colors:  Items:
Green    Courgette
Yellow   Banana
```

For retrieving all the colors, one would normally use `$Stuff.Colors` or `$Stuff | Select-Object -Property Colors`.

Because the label `Colors` is often changing in my script, it would be nice if it could just select the property name based on it's location. Because I know it will always be the first property, something like `$Stuff.[Property0]` would be nice. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is this:

```
$stuff | select -Property  ($stuff | gm | ? { $_.membertype -eq 'noteproperty' })[0].name
```

or

```
$stuff | select -Property  ($stuff[0].psobject.properties | select -expa name)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you CB, the first one works perfectly! The second one seems easier to read but it's not giving any result except for `Count:`.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Glad to help! Are you on powershell version 2.0 or >3.0?

Comment: Your help is really appreciated, for the moment we are on PowerShell 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can select first property of PSCustomObject in this way

```
$CustomObject1 = New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
$CustomObject1.psobject.properties | select-object -Property Name -first 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not generating the same output as above. Because it only selects the label name. The result it retrieved was `c`, while it should only give me `3` and all other stuff under the label `c`.